# Hide div with buttons when user uses a touch screen in a functional react component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, react-functional-component

I would like to hide a div when the user uses a touchscreen. It's a react js functional component.

The div I want to hide looks like this:

```
    <div className="scrollButtons">
                    <button
                        className={count <= 0 ? 'buttonLeftOpacity' : 'buttonLeft'}
                        type="button"
                        onMouseDown={() => clickHandlerLeft()}
                    >
                        {'<'}
                    </button>
                    <button className="buttonRight" type="button" onMouseDown={() => clickHandlerRight()}>
                        {'>'}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </>
```

The code I use to sense if the user is on a touch screen is this:

```
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', function userTouch() {
        console.log(userTouch());
    });
```

How can I use that code to hide the div when a user uses a touch screen?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, This is how I solved it. By using "useState" from react, I set show by default to true, and to false if the user is on a touchscreen. I then use that state to show or hide the touchbuttons-div if the value is true or not.

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

    window.addEventListener('touchstart', function userTouch() {
        setShow(false);
    })

{show ? (
                <>
                    <div className="scrollButtons" id="scrollButtons">
                        <button
                            className={count <= 0 ? 'buttonLeftOpacity' : 'buttonLeft'}
                            type="button"
                            onMouseDown={() => clickHandlerLeft()}
                        >
                            {'<'}
                        </button>
                        <button className="buttonRight" type="button" onMouseDown={() => clickHandlerRight()}>
                            {'>'}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </>
            ) : (
                <></>
            )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a class that won't display

```
.example {
display:none; 
}
```

And then add this

```
 window.addEventListener('touchstart', function userTouch() {
  var element = document.getElementById("scrollbuttons"); // selecting the element you want to edit, make sure to add the ID to the button if you are using this method. 
  element.classList.add("example"); //add invisible className
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I liked it and I actually tried something similar before - and it works - but I don't think that it feels like a React way to do it. Maybe more if I only used Javascript. I posted and answer of how I solved it with state.

Comment: No problem, what ever works for you. I'm glad you could find several ways to solve this problem. 
Go ahead and mark your answer as the solution, and could you please give my answer an upvote?

Comment: Can't mark my answer as the solution until tomorrow for some reason,  but an upvote you have received! Thanks again! ✌